# Symplectic forms on $\mathbb{C}P^3$

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry

Combining results of Gromov, McDuff, Taubes shows that any two symplectic forms on $\mathbb{C}P^2$ with the same total volume are symplectomorphic (e.g. to the Fubini-Study form $\omega_{FS}$). See for example McDuff-Salamon's book. Is there an analagous result for symplectic forms on $\mathbb{C}P^3$? McDuff-Salamon do not mention anything about this.

Suppose $\omega_1,\omega_2$ are symplectic forms on $\mathbb{C}P^3$ such that the almost complex structures $J_1,J_2$ tamed by these forms have $c_1(T\mathbb{C}P^3,J_1)=c_1(T\mathbb{C}P^3,J_2)$. Are the forms homotopic through symplectic forms? Symplectomorphic?

Any references would be appreciated, also for other symplectic 6-manifolds.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is a wide open problem. Also, it is completely unknown whether there are symplectic forms on $\mathbb{CP}^3$ such that $c_{1} = 2nH$  for $n \neq 2$ and $H$ is the hyperplane class. This for me is a nice example of why symplectic geometry in dimensions greater than 4 is very mysterious and in some sense not much is known about it.